# ObjC: [self.items enumerate...] is self.item (derived) generated every time inside block?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

In one of my classes I have a derived property called items, it is basically like:

```
- (NSArray *)items
{
    [self.unsortedSet.allValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptor:...];
}
```

then in some other place:

```
[self.items enumerateUsingBlock...{
    // do something with item
}]
```

in this case, if self.items has X items, then does the enumeration block generate self.items X times? Or is it more safer to:

```
NSArray *sortedItems = self.items;
[sortedItems enumerateUsingBlock...{}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then does the enumeration block generate self.items X times?

No. Just once. This is for semantics and efficiency.

> Or is it more safe to…

semantics depend on your implementation.